# Which is more efficient Water heating method : Electric heating coil OR Induction stove?

Tags: induction

Which is more efficient Water heating method : Electric heating coil Vs Induction stove

Comment: If you have a glass pot, the answer is obvious.

Comment: Do you know the working of both methods?

Comment: And yes, it depends that what do you mean by "efficient" here. If you are referring to the efficiency according to the time taken for heating a specific amount of water to a particular temperature, then the answer will be different and if you're referring to efficiency according to the Energy taken, then the answer will be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is everything 100% efficient at heating?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88780/is-everything-100-efficient-at-heating)

Answer (score 1):

according to this US Environmental Protection Agency document:

http://www.epa.gov/region9/islands/conf09/Kelly-Cutchin.pdf

efficiency for an induction cooktop is 90% verus 65% for electric resistance cooktop.